# Looping selected Tag first and then all tags

Tags: javascript, html, vb6, webbrowser-control

In VB6 I want to loop through all the html tags in a web browser control. It becomes slow as html contents is large. Below is my requirement.

I want to get a "A" (anchor) tag with a specific name which will be unique in that document.(Example  ). After getting
that tag i want to loop through all html tags until i get another "A" tag with another specific name. (for ex

So i used below code.The code is done by checking for some characters in attribute name as it works in same way. The code is not as per my requirement i explained as i did it another way.

```
Dim bkm As Boolean
Dim hw2 As HTMLWindow2
 For Each ele In hw2.Document.All

        If ele.getAttribute("name") = mybkm Then 'mybkm  variable having name of tag
            bkm = True

            ele.Style.cssText = "background-color:#FFFFEB;" & ele.Style.cssText

        ElseIf bkm = True And InStr(ele.outerHTML, "name=BKM") = 0) Then
            ele.Style.cssText = "background-color:#FFFFEB;" & ele.Style.cssText
        ElseIf InStr(ele.getAttribute("name"), "BKM") > 0 Then
            If bkm = True Then
                bkm = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

But in my this getting first occurrence of A tag with that name becomes very slow(it takes about 90% of time of whole process) due to large no. of tags like P,br,A,table etc etc

So I am planning to get first "A" tag with specific name(may be just by looping though "A" tag) and then loop though all tags untill i get next "A" tag.

So how it can be done?

Comment: Are you saying that despite the fact that this code does not fit your requirements, you posted it anyway, knowing that you "did it another way"? Why not post this other code?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try like this - 

Dim i As Integer
Dim anchorElement As HTMLAnchorElement = wbMain.Document.All.getElementByTagName("A")(0)

For i = 0 To anchorElement.attributes.length - 1
  MsgBox anchorElement.attributes.item(i).name & "=" & anchorElement.attributes.item(i).value
Next i
```

Comment: U have just done loop though "A" tag. That is not my requirement. After getting slected A tag how can i loop though remaining all tags,not only A. Please read the question. if any doubts ask me

Comment: All elements are anchor elements or elements of some other type?

Comment: So I am planning to get first "A" tag with specific name(may be just by looping though "A" tag) and then loop though all tags(it may be a,br,table,td,tr etc) untill i get next "A" tag. Its only to speed up the process of getting first A tag with specific name

Comment: check this link - http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Parsing-Html-Table-t1967305.html

Comment: check this link too - http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?373652-RESOLVED-Loop-Through-HTML-Form-Elements!

Comment: I have already seen those links. Thats a simple loop through all tags or selected tags. but my requirement is little different.Also see my edited question